Tools to crack AES-GCM when IV is reused
I have read multiple times that data encrypted with the AES-GCM scheme fails catastrophically if you reuse the IV in different instances, leaking the XOR table (to my understanding this means no key recovery, but I can use the XOR table to decrypt/encrypt at will).
Let's say that I have two files that I have encrypted with the same key and I intentionally reused the IV to test this theory. But I can't find any tool readily available to do it.
Should I implement this by myself? Is there any reference implementation out there or is this attack still theoretical?

The condition for the attack you are thinking about is that the Initialization Vector and the key are both reused, and two other standard assumptions: something is known about at least one plaintext (e.g. it's known in full, or it's known to be English text in ASCII), and ciphertexts are available. Reusing the same IV for distinct secret keys is much less disastrous (but still not academically OK, especially if AES-128 is used).

If the same IV (or rather nonce) is used then the same key stream - generated by AES-CTR is generated. Simply XOR'ing the ciphertext - minus tag - will result in a XOR of the plaintext. In other words, you would be solving a many-time-pad.
The more streams of data, and the more is known about the bits inside the other streams the easier it gets as you can XOR any stream with any other stream, and a single known bit at one location will mean it can be used to see that same bit in any other stream. But this is already talking about cracking a many-time-pad and there is tons of information available about how to proceed with that.
Of course, if you have just 2 streams and one of them contains unknown, fully randomized data then it will not be possible to know anything about the data in the other stream, as a XOR of both streams will still require you to solve a one-time-pad. So in that case (or in the case that one stream is larger than the others) you can only tell anything about the stream by guessing it from context. The same situation arises when one stream is larger than the others.
As you may have guessed the key cannot be retrieved. The simple reason for that is that it is always protected by the AES block cipher, which hasn't been broken. That however is not the case for the security of the authentication tag. That's another reason why reuse of the IV is so catastrophic.
